# Adding controls to HTML5 background video with CSS

Tags: css, html, video, accessibility

I've stuggled to find an answer to this problem, I would like to add controls to HTML5 background video, so that users can at least choose to pause the video for accessibility reasons. The built-in HTML5  "Controls" attribute work just fine but as soon as I add my CSS to put the video in the background, the controls disappear. How do I keep the controls and have the video in the background?

Here is my simple HTML5 code:

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video controls loop muted autoplay poster="Rustypic.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg-video">
        <source src="Rustybeg.webm" srclang="en" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS that puts the video in the background:

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How did the controls disappear in the first place? were they just off the bottom of the screen? I have a 'background' video for which I don't want controls! opposite problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4ac21ch6/1/)?

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}
.fullscreen-bg-video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video controls loop muted autoplay poster="Rustypic.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg-video">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<div class="content">NASA is not about the ‘Adventure of Human Space Exploration’…We won’t be doing it just to get out there in space – we’ll be doing it because the things we learn out there will be making life better for a lot of people who won’t be able to go.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note - you don't really need the height 100% unless you want the video centered on the page for some reason.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and would be better suited as a comment.